# NSFetchedResultsController finds wrong number of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm seeing a situation where a NSFetchRequest returns a different number of objects depending on whether it's executed directly through the NSManagedObjectContext or as part of building a NSFetchedResultsController.

Sample code:

```
- (void)setupResultsController {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *ctx = [[DataManager sharedInstance] mainObjectContext];

    // Create a fetch request and execute it directly
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [Song entityInManagedObjectContext:ctx];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"section" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor, nameDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSArray *debugResults = [ctx executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Count from context fetch: %lu", (unsigned long)debugResults.count);

    // Use the request to populate a NSFetchedResultsController
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                                             initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                             managedObjectContext:ctx
                                                             sectionNameKeyPath:@"section"
                                                             cacheName:@"Detail"];
    [aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    NSLog(@"Count from results controller fetch: %lu", (unsigned long)[[aFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]);

    _songResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
}
```

Executing the above results in log messages:

**2020-01-10 11:05:07.892772-0500 asb7[12985:105052] Count from context fetch: 10**

**2020-01-10 11:05:07.893259-0500 asb7[12985:105052] Count from results controller fetch: 9**

The difference between the two fetches is that the NSFetchedResultsController is missing the most recently added object.  An extreme oddity about this is that, after running the application some seemingly random number of times, the counts start to agree and the new object is fetched.

**Edit:**

The results become consistent if I pass `nil` as the cache name or if I remove the second sort descriptor.  Obviously these cause undesirable behavior changes but may be clues.

It seems that the NSFetchedResultsController is seeing a stale cache as being valid.  Changing a sort descriptor invalidates the cache however updating the persistent store file **should** invalidate it but apparently does not in this case.

After a bit more experimenting, I have an explanation...if not a solution.  Adding new objects does not change the modification date of my .sqlite file.  It updates the .sqlite-shm and .sqlite-wal but I'll guess those aren't considered when judging whether to use the cache.  Using `touch` from a terminal session makes the problem go away for the next launch.

(Xcode 10.1, macOS 10.13.6, deployment target 10.3, iOS 12.1 simulator and 10.3.2 device)

**Another edit:**

I've uploaded a zipped project directory that demonstrates the problem at https://github.com/PhilKMills/CacheTest

What I get is: first run, 3 records for both fetches; second run, 6 and 3.  I see it as entirely possible that this depends on my particular software versions but I'm not in a position to upgrade at the moment.  Other people's results would be most interesting.

Note: without a FRC delegate being assigned, the problem does not appear.

Comment: Does the problem remain if you don't use the FRC cache?

Comment: @pbasdf That gets the 2 fetches in sync and so does something I was trying: removing the 2nd sort descriptor.  Updating question....

Comment: A few lines of enquiry: 1) does using SQLDebug reveal anything helpful in the logs; 2) does changing the journal mode to avoid using WAL mode change the behaviour; 3) does changing `includesPendingChanges` for the fetchrequest affect things.

Comment: I tried item 3 early on with no change.  I'll get back to you about the others when I figure out how to do those.  Thanks!

Comment: @pbasdf It looks as if getting rid of WAL mode fixes the problem.  I just ran a couple of tests after adding an option of `NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}` and the .sqlite file's modification time is being updated.  Thanks again!  (You should add an answer here.)

Comment: It feels like more of a workaround than an answer, but it might help someone else in the future, so I'll add it (when I have a little more time).

Comment: But this is nuts; surely if this were normal we’d all know about it! It would make Core Data impossible to use. Is there something odd about how you’re adding the objects?

Comment: @matt  There's nothing unusual that I can see.  If I use `sqlite3` from the command line to inspect the database, the records I expect to see are reported correctly and, as I mentioned, using the context to do the fetch gets the right answer also.  (The program was working correctly in previous versions, though whether that was pre-WAL, I'm not certain.)

Comment: Well I think this is at least enough to file a bug report to Apple. Esp if the sort descriptors change the behavior.

Comment: The thing with the sort descriptors is really just evidence that it really is a cache problem.  That's one of the things CoreData is supposed to use for checking whether the cache is valid.  I've just thrown together a tiny app that reproduces the problem.  I'll see about making that publicly available for people to poke at.

Comment: Another detail that might make this a rare problem is your CoreData stack.  For the changes to hit the store without going through the FRC's context, I guess you have a separate context on the same persistent store coordinator (or, indeed, a separate PSC accessing the same store)?  If so, that might make it rare enough to have not been picked up before.

Comment: Same context.  The app doesn't need any background, or otherwise tricky, access.  If you have a chance to look at my github mini-app, you'll see it's amazingly straightforward.  I did learn one more detail while creating the mini: without a FRC delegate, the numbers stay in sync.

Comment: But darn it, I was going to suggest you use the FRC delegate to detect that the source has changed!

Comment: Tried your example project. Problem still there in Xcode 11.3, Simulator 13.3 running on macOS 10.15.2.

Comment: Thanks.  I've just submitted a bug report through Apple's feedback system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspected that the issue related to the use of the FRC cache, though I was uncertain why that might be.  One workaround would therefore be to abandon using the FRC cache.  However, that's not ideal.

After further experimentation by the OP, it seems the problem relates to the timestamp on the `.sqlite` file associated with the persistent store.  By inference(*), if the FRC detects that the timestamp has changed, it realises that its cache might be out of date, and rebuilds it - thereby detecting the newly added objects.  However, because CoreData by default uses SQLite's "WAL journal mode" (see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) and [here](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)), database updates are written not to the `.sqlite` file, but instead to a separate `.sqlite-wal` file: the timestamp on the `.sqlite` file is consequently not changed, even though the database has been updated.  The FRC continues to use its cache, unaware of the additional objects (or indeed other changes).

A second workaround is therefore to abandon using SQLite's WAL journal mode. This can be achieved by specifying the required journal mode when loading the persistent store, using

```
NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}
```

see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/store_options).

(*) In fact, this is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller):

> “the controller tests the cache to determine whether its contents are still valid. The controller compares the current entity name, entity version hash, sort descriptors, and section key-path with those stored in the cache, as well as the modification date of the cached information file and the persistent store file.”