# @FetchRequest results not updating in SwiftUI when change source is share extension

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

There are many questions on @FetchRequest with answers that provide workarounds for forcing SwiftUI to redraw the view. I can't find any that address this question.

My app uses a share extension to insert a new item into my `CoreData` model (sqlite). A framework is shared between the main app and the share extension target. The main SwiftUI `ContentView` in my app uses a `@FetchRequest` property to monitor the contents of the database and update the view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: MyObj.allFetchRequest()) var allObjs: FetchedResults<MyObj>
    ...
}
```

my xcdatamodel is extended with:

```swift
    public static func allFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<MyObj> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<MyObj> = MyObj.fetchRequest()
        // update request to sort by name
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        return request
    }
```

The share extension adds a new item using:

```swift
let newObj = MyObj(context: context)
newObj.name = "new name"
try! context.save()
```

After adding a new item using the share extension, when I return to my app by switching apps on the device, `SceneDelegate` detects `sceneDidBecomeActive`. In this function, I can manually run a fetch request and see that the new item has been added. I can even use answers from other SO questions to trick the UI into rebuilding in ContentView (by toggling a Bool used in the builder on receipt of a notification), but in either case, when the UI rebuilds, `allObjs` does not contain the updated results from the database.

In my `sceneDidBecomeActive` I have tried numerous combinations of code to attempt to update the context with the latest contents of the database in a way that the `@FetchRequest` will see it. The data is there, and the my managed context can see this new data because a manual fetch request returns the new item, but the `@FetchRequest` is always stale preventing a UI rebuild. In both locations I've printed the context and am sure that it is the same context. I've tried:

- `context.reset()`
- `context.refreshAllObjects()`
- `context.save()`

I'm at a loss as to why the `@FetchRequest` is not updating its values when `ContentView` redraws.

How can I force `@FetchRequest` to update its objects and cause a SwiftUI rebuild after my share extension adds a new object to the database?

(Xcode 11.4.1, Swift 5, target: iOS 13.1)

**edit:**

In my `ContentView`, I print the `allObjs` variables, their state, the memory address of the context, *etc.* I compare this to a new fetch from the context and all values for existing objects are the same, except the new fetch shows the newly added object, whereas `allObjs` does not contain the new object. It is very clear that the `@FetchRequest` object is not getting updated.

**edit 2:**

I tried creating a custom `ObservableObject` class with a `@Published` property and an explicit `update()` method, then using it as an `@ObservedObject` in `ContentView`. This works.

```swift
class MyObjList: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = MyObjList()
    @Published var allObjs: [MyObj]!

    init() {
        update()
    }

    func update() {
        allObjs = try! DataStore.persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(MyObj.allFetchRequest())
    }
}
```

Then in `ContentView`:

```swift
@EnvironmentObject var allObjs: MyObjList
```

Which helps confirm that the data is there, it just isn't getting updated properly by `@FetchRequest`. This is a functional workaround.

Comment: if you Aad the same object inside of your app (not an extension), will it appear in @FetchRequest?

Comment: @Aspid yes, the same object created in the app (not extension) appears with no problem. Bear in mind it is created in the same context that is displayed by the `ContentView`

Comment: I just wonder if this is another example of a problem with WAL mode and FRC caches.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59706590/3985749) for further info.

Comment: @pbasdf Interesting stuff I was unaware of. I tried `let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription; storeDescription.setValue("DELETE" as NSString, forPragmaNamed: "journal_mode")` and adding the description to the `NSPersistentContainer()`, but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry.  That was a red herring then.

Comment: fwiw, https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode says that DELETE is the "normal behavior". In the description of WAL, it mentions that this mode is persistent across closing/reopening the database, so I removed the installation of my app to start from scratch and ensure the database is initially created in DELETE mode. No effect.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this is unrelated to SwiftUI. A managed object context does not track “external” changes, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/29563667/1187415

Comment: @MartinR Agreed. The update happens in the context in the share extension. But in my case I've signaled my main app that the database has updated. This signal is detected by my app's  `sceneDidBecomeActive` method, at which time I would like to update the current context so `@FetchRequest` contents will be updated from as well from disk. While I can use the context to run a fetch and see the new data, the `@FetchRequest` does not update.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue.  Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: @alionthego, it's been a long time since I've looked into this, but I never found a solution better than the workaround in edit 2

Comment: thanks.  I've tried that and it works with my extension.  I'm having a separate but related issue when saving on a privateContext the fetchRequest does not update and that method doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem using persistent history tracking and remote change notifications. These make Core Data record every change that occurs to an SQLite store and sends you notifications whenever one of these changes occurred remotely (eg from an extension or iCloud).

These features aren't enabled by default. You have to configure them before loading the persistent stores:

```swift
persistentStoreDescriptions.forEach {
    $0.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
    $0.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
}
```

Then subscribe to remote change notifications:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    /* The persistent container/view model/MyObjList/etc that acts as observer */, 
    selector: #selector(coordinatorReceivedRemoteChanges(_:)), 
    name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, 
    object: persistentStoreCoordinator // don't forget to pass the PSC as the object!
)
```

Now we will be notified when remote changes occur, but we need to share these changes with the managed object contexts throughout the app. This looks different for every app: sometimes your MOCs don't need to know about the changes at all, sometimes they only need to know about some of them, sometimes all of them. Apple recently [published a guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/consuming_relevant_store_changes) that goes into depth about how to ensure only relevant changes are processed.

In this scenario you might do:

```swift
@objc
func coordinatorReceivedRemoteChanges(_ notification: Notification) {
    let currentToken = notification.userInfo?[NSPersistentHistoryTokenKey] as? NSPersistentHistoryToken
    let existingToken = ... // retrieve the previously processed history token so we don't repeat work; you might have saved it to disk using NSKeyedArchiver
    
    // Fetch the history
    let historyRequest = NSPersistentHistoryChangeRequest.fetchHistory(after: existingToken)
    let result = try! context.execute(historyRequest) as! NSPersistentHistoryResult
    let transactions = result.result as! [NSPersistentHistoryTransaction]

    // Filter out the non-relevant changes
    for transaction in transaction {
        // Maybe we only care about changes to MyObjs 
        guard transaction.entityDescription.name == MyObj.entity().name else { continue }
        // Maybe we only care about specific kinds of changes
        guard let changes = transaction.changes, changes.contains(where: { ... }) else { continue }
        // Merge transaction into the view context
        viewContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: transaction.objectIDNotification())
    }

    // Finally, save `currentToken` so it can be used next time and optionally delete old history.
}
```

Any `@FetchRequest`s using `viewContext` will now receive all merged changes and refresh their data accordingly.

Comment: Had the exact same issue than the original question. This solution worked for me. The only change I made was to use `.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange), perform: refresh)` on my main view. Though that really depends on the app

Comment: This works great. I've found more details about persistent history tracking and some improvements to the code above here: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/persistent-history-tracking-core-data/

Answer (score 0):

I use the method from the comment referred [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563667/refresh-nsmanagedobjectcontext). I can resolve the ManagedID from URI. But can not retrieve the object by `existingObject(with:)`. Only nil returns. And the `object(with:)` method crash the app.

```
020-05-13 18:34:54.324914+0800 SwiftUI-FetchRequest[7802:388610] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Object's persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e39f0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50ad79b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreData                            0x00007fff23a0b0a9 -[_NSCoreManagedObjectID _isPersistentStoreAlive] + 0
    3   CoreData                            0x00007fff239f704a -[NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID:] + 555
    4   SwiftUI-FetchRequest                0x000000010e922933 $s20SwiftUI_FetchRequest16ContentViewModelCACycfcyypSgcfU_ + 1827
    5   SwiftUI-FetchRequest                0x000000010e922d21 $sypSgIegn_yXlSgIeyBy_TR + 161
    6   MMWormhole                          0x000000010ebbfe34 __61-[MMWormhole notifyListenerForMessageWithIdentifier:message:]_block_invoke + 36
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ebe1f11 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ebe2e8e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ebf0d97 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1149
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9da89 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d985d9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2041
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d97ac4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38b2fc1a GSEventRunModal + 139
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48bc7f80 UIApplicationMain + 1605
    15  SwiftUI-FetchRequest                0x000000010e920c3b main + 75
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff519521fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The context is already refresh by `reset()` method. And manually query the latest entry could be resolved correctly. I think its SwiftUI.framework bug. And file a issue by Feedback.app.

Comment: The methods described in the answer you linked do not seem to update the `@FetchRequest` property wrapper. My app itself can *see* the new objects in the context—its just the fetched results in the property wrapper are not updated.

Comment: Yes. @FetchRequest is buggy. And basically there is no way to fix a black box property wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

Try to move, if it is applicable for your app, creation of `ContentView` on app go to foreground (thus fetch request will be recreated from scratch)

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    // leave here only window creation
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        self.window = window
    }
}

// ... other code here

func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)

    window?.rootViewController = controller
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. This is a workaround, and a rather heavyweight one at that.